# Stacking value by duplicating some other columns also in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, stack

I have data-frame like thi:

df

```
ID              Brands          Age           Gender           City
1             BMW_Audi_VW       50             M               Milano
2               VW_BMW          45             F               SF
```

I would like to split the `Brands` column on "_" and want to duplicate all columns except `City`

I can do based based on ID column like this:

```
df = df.set_index('ID').stack().str.split('_', expand=True).unstack(-1).stack(0).reset_index()
```

but it duplicate only ID column. I need all columns but not "City"

Here is the **desired output** that i am looking for:

```
ID              Brands          Age           Gender           City
 1             BMW               50             M               Milano
 1             Audi              50             M               None
 1             VW                50             M               None
 2             VW                45             F               SF
 2             BMW               45             F               None
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) with splitted columns values by [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) and then set `None`s by [`DataFrame.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html):

```
df = df.assign(Brands = df['Brands'].str.split('_')).explode('Brands')

include = ['ID','Brands','Age','Gender']
cols = df.columns.difference(include)
df[cols] = df[cols].mask(df.index.to_series().duplicated(), None)
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
   ID Brands  Age Gender    City
0   1    BMW   50      M  Milano
1   1   Audi   50      M    None
2   1     VW   50      M    None
3   2     VW   45      F      SF
4   2    BMW   45      F    None
```

EDIT:

Check difference:

```
#Brands column is assigned to Brands column (to same column)
df1= df.assign(Brands = df['Brands '].str.split('_')).explode('Brands')
print (df1)
   ID Brands  Age Gender    City
0   1    BMW   50      M  Milano
0   1   Audi   50      M  Milano
0   1     VW   50      M  Milano
1   2     VW   45      F      SF
1   2    BMW   45      F      SF

#Brands column is assigned to Brands1 column (to another column)
df2 = df.assign(Brands1 = df['Brands'].str.split('_')).explode('Brands')
print (df2)
   ID       Brands  Age Gender    City          Brands1
0   1  BMW_Audi_VW   50      M  Milano  [BMW, Audi, VW]
1   2       VW_BMW   45      F      SF        [VW, BMW]
```

Comment: Is there any possibility if i dont want to specify specifically "City"? Because i have alot other columns in the same dataframe which i  just dont want to duplicate

Comment: @s_khan92 - So you have list of columns for not duplicate?

Comment: I dont have list but if i have to create the list then its fine too... But is there not any way that we specifiy directly only the column which have to be duplicated?

Comment: @s_khan92 - So logic is there is small list for duplicate  columns and all another columns are not duplicated?

Comment: Yes exactly... Because there is a large list of columns which i dont want to duplicate. So, its better to use list of columns which should be duplicated.

Comment: @s_khan92 - OK, give me second

Comment: Can you also again provide your last solution which you gave only for one column "City"? and for curent it didnt explode but it converted into list.. like this ['BMW', 'Audi'. 'VW']

Comment: @s_khan92 - This solution is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/60949842/2)

Comment: Thanks but that solution is also creating only the list... Its not exploding into rows :(

Comment: @s_khan92 - There is used `explode` ?

Comment: `df = df.assign(Brands = df['Brands'].str.split('_')).explode('Brands')` yes

Comment: @s_khan92 - and there is created list, from `Brand` column?

Comment: @s_khan92 - There is one problem posible, answer was edited.